# Casting int pointer (array) to int typed-memoryview in Cython throws ValueError at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting, cython, typed-memory-views

#### Problem Description

I have this function:

```py
def test(unsigned int N):
    cdef int *my_arr = <int *> malloc(N * sizeof(int))
    cdef int[:] new_arr = <int[:N]>my_arr
    free(my_arr)
```

When I put it on a single isolated file called test.pyx, compile it and call it from CPython's interpreter, **it works fine**. I call it like this:

```py
import test
test.test(10)
```

The problem comes when I add this function to an existing lib (in a big project with multiple files and dependencies), it compiles fine but throws an error when I call it:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "av/video/frame.pyx", line 37, in av.video.frame.test
    cdef int[:] new_arr = <int[:N]>my_arr
ValueError
```

as you can see, it specifically complains about this line:

```py
cdef int[:] new_arr = <int[:N]>my_arr
```

The function is exactly the same in both cases, and I pass the same N value, it's really weird.

Does anybody know in which context could a simple cast from `int *` to `int[:]` throw a ValueError?

---

#### Context

I'm trying to add some functionality to the PyAV library, so I'm adding that function to this file:

https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/av/video/frame.pyx

and it throws when I just call it like this:

```py
import av
av.video.frame.test(10)
```

I'm on MacOS 10.15.7, using Python 3.7.7 and Cython 0.29.21 with Clang 11.0.3 compiler.

---

#### Update 1

I've checked the C code generated by Cython for the `test()` function and it's the same in both cases, this is the code generated for the problematic line:

```
 /* "av/video/frame.pyx":37
 * def test(unsigned int N):
 *     cdef int *my_arr = <int *> malloc(N * sizeof(int))
 *     cdef int[:] new_arr = <int[:N]>my_arr             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     free(my_arr)
 * 
 */
  if (!__pyx_v_my_arr) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Cannot create cython.array from NULL pointer");
    __PYX_ERR(0, 37, __pyx_L1_error)
  }
  __pyx_t_3 = __pyx_format_from_typeinfo(&__Pyx_TypeInfo_int); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_3)) __PYX_ERR(0, 37, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_3);
  __pyx_t_2 = Py_BuildValue((char*) "("  __PYX_BUILD_PY_SSIZE_T  ")", ((Py_ssize_t)__pyx_v_N)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 37, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
  __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_array_new(__pyx_t_2, sizeof(int), PyBytes_AS_STRING(__pyx_t_3), (char *) "c", (char *) __pyx_v_my_arr);
  if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 37, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_2 = 0;
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_3 = 0;
  __pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_int(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1), PyBUF_WRITABLE); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4.memview)) __PYX_ERR(0, 37, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_DECREF(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1)); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
  __pyx_v_new_arr = __pyx_t_4;
  __pyx_t_4.memview = NULL;
  __pyx_t_4.data = NULL;
```

So I started commenting lines with `__PYX_ERR()` calls and found that the one raising the ValueError is this:

```
__pyx_t_4 = __Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_int(((PyObject *)__pyx_t_1), PyBUF_WRITABLE); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_4.memview)) __PYX_ERR(0, 37, __pyx_L1_error)
```

This line updates a `__Pyx_memviewslice` that is declared earlier as:

```
__Pyx_memviewslice __pyx_t_4 = { 0, 0, { 0 }, { 0 }, { 0 } };
```

This function is likely to be setting the error:

`__Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_ds_int()`

so maybe the cast `(PyObject *)__pyx_t_1` is doing something wrong or `__pyx_t_1` is not what it expects.

But I really don't know how all this works so maybe there is something else causing this behaviour, like some compiler flag maybe?

Comment: It's going to be very very very hard to tell from your description. My best guess would be that something else has set the exception state and not cleared it, and yours is the first code to check it. But that is a complete guess

Comment: Thank you for responding. I can give you more context if needed, but don’t know what else would be useful information, if you could give me a hint. I’m just adding the function to frame.pyx, without changing anything else from the PyAV lib, and compiling it with the configuration as they have it in their GitHub repo. About your guess, not sure what else can set the exception state, if I comment the line with the cast it stops throwing.

Comment: It's quite hard to know what to suggest. You could try test the exception state by adding `PyErr_Clear` before the line that fails (you'll need to `cimport` it from `cpython.exc`). It's also quite likely that this isn't the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried with PyErr_Clear before the cast but it keeps complaining about it. I also checked the generated C code for that line and it's exactly the same regardless of whether it fails or not, so I assume it may be something related to the compiler.

Comment: I really don't know then. It might be worth checking the return value from malloc isn't NULL (but I think that gives you a more specific error).

Comment: I checked by assigning some values to `my_arr` and printing them before the cast, and it prints them correctly, it only complains about the casting. Anyway, I found the C line that throws the error, I updated the post with new information.

Comment: If I were you what I'd do is start deleting stuff from frame.pyx. Is there something specific that causes the issue to go away when you delete it? Does it work if you delete everything but your test function from frame.pyx?